# Check device Bluetooth state in cordova javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, bluetooth

I'm developing an application that use beacons (BLE) to fire some events and do work according to it. For the application to work properly the bluetooth must be on. I need to inform the user to turn on his bluetooth when off in order to use the app. Is there a phonegap/cordova plugin to check the bluetooth state?

Comment: If you are using a BLE plugin , there must be a function that let you know whether your bluetooth is on or off

Comment: What plugin are you using?